# return single values for multiple records

Tags: vba, excel

Is there a way to merge multiple records then display only the highest value for each column?  Example: A2:A25=names, B2=Grade1, C2=Grade2...etc. 
First I removed duplicates in case there are exact duplicates. Then I sort on Name.
Can something be added to this code, based on column A-names, to display each name once with the highest value from each column?
=IF(B2="","Empty",IF(B2="High","High",IF(B2="Med","Med",IF(B2="Low","Low",""))))

Data Example

```
A1:name B1:Grade1 C1:Grade2...etc
A2:Joe B2:High C3:Low
A3:Joe B3:Med C3:High
A4:Dan B4:Low C4:Med
A5:Dan B5:Low C5:Low
```

__Results: Joe Grade1=high Grade2=high, Dan: Grade1=Low Grade2=Med

Comment: You tag with excel-vba, but you give an example that is a formula you would put in a cell. Are you wanting a macro or a formula?

Comment: Where do you want to have this result displayed? How many columns will be there? Are there only 3 grades (high, low, medium)? Are you ok with a vba solution?

Answer (score 0):

Record an Excel macro. Select first column. Click advanced filter.Choose copy to location and select a new column say X. Enable unique filter. Now click Ok. Now look at vba source to get the code to get unique elements in a column. Now assign Low as 0, Med as 1, High as 2 . loop through the rows and find the maximum grade1 , maximum grade2 etc corresponding to each element in column X and populate columns Y,Z etc. As and when you find a new maximum replace the existing. Now you will have the required data in columns X,Y,Z. Loop through them again and display in the format what you needed.

Answer (score 0):

Decided to try VBA code for this one. It's a bit bruitish, but gets the job done.

Took a shortcut and made columns b and c numbers rather than strings. You could do a lookup function on the spreadsheet to make that conversion, or add an extra check in the code.

```
Sub find_high_values()
' subroutine to find max values of columns b and c against names
' assumes for simplicity that there are no more than 10 rows
' assumes values being checked to be numbers, if they are strings, additional loops would need to be done
Dim sName(10) As String, lBval(10) As Long, lCval(10) As Long 'arrays for original list
Dim iCountN As Integer, iUnique As Integer, iUniqueCount As Integer 'counters
Dim bUnique As Boolean
Dim rStart As Range, rOutput As Range 'ranges on worksheet
Dim lBmax(10) As Long, lCmax(10) As Long, sUniqueName(10) As String 'output arrays

Set rStart = ActiveSheet.Range("d6") 'Cell immediately above the first name in list
Set rOutput = ActiveSheet.Range("j6") 'cell reference for max value list
iUniqueCount = 1
For iCountN = 1 To 10 'set max counters to a min value
    lBmax(iCountN) = 0
    lCmax(iCountN) = 0
Next

For iCountN = 1 To 10 'step through each original row
    sName(iCountN) = rStart.Offset(iCountN, 0).Value
    lBval(iCountN) = rStart.Offset(iCountN, 1).Value
    lCval(iCountN) = rStart.Offset(iCountN, 2).Value
    bUnique = True 'Starter value, assume the name to be unique, changes to false if already in list
    For iUnique = 1 To iCountN 'loop to check if it is a new name
        If sUniqueName(iUnique) = sName(iCountN) Then bUnique = False
    Next
    If bUnique Then 'if new name, add to list of names
        sUniqueName(iUniqueCount) = sName(iCountN)
        iUniqueCount = iUniqueCount + 1
    End If
Next
iUniqueCount = iUniqueCount - 1 'make the count back to total number of names found
For iUnique = 1 To iUniqueCount 'loop through names
    For iCountN = 1 To 10 'loop through all values
        If sName(iCountN) = sUniqueName(iUnique) Then
            If lBval(iCountN) > lBmax(iUnique) Then lBmax(iUnique) = lBval(iCountN)
            If lCval(iCountN) > lCmax(iUnique) Then lCmax(iUnique) = lCval(iCountN)
        End If
    Next
Next

'output section
rStart.Resize(1, 3).Select
Selection.Copy
rOutput.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

For iUnique = 1 To iUniqueCount
    rOutput.Offset(iUnique, 0).Value = sUniqueName(iUnique)
    rOutput.Offset(iUnique, 1).Value = lBmax(iUnique)
    rOutput.Offset(iUnique, 2).Value = lCmax(iUnique)
 Next

End Sub
```